# Curvature approaching infinity

Tags: black-holes, curvature

I assume that all mass-objects curve time-space but the curvature is only measurable with celestial bodies large enough to be significant gravity-wells.
What you call "curvature" seems to me to be only a graphic representation-- a map-- of the varying thickness of time-space, a curve which being continuous can be rendered by Calculus. What is being diagrammed is the continuous function of varying thickness within a more ultimate field.

My question is: Do we have any idea how the thickness varies inside the Schwarzschild radius? Does the curvature go to infinity (graphed by an orthogonal vertical line) at the singularity? Or does the curvature go to infinity at the Schwarzschild radius?
Can a form of Calculus be profitably applied to a mass-object of infinite thickness?

Answer (score 2):

> What you call "curvature" seems to me to be only a graphic representation-- a map-- of the varying thickness of time-space, a curve which being continuous can be rendered by Calculus.

Curvature is a well-defined notion in terms of what happens to a vector when it is parallel-transported around a small loop. Wikipedia has a pretty good [motivation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_tensor#Geometrical_meaning) for what this means intuitively.

In particular, curvature can generally be reduced to a single number *only* in two dimensions. This scalar curvature could be vaguely compared to "thickness" in the case of Riemannian geometry (really an area defect of small discs when compared to flatness), but not quite that well in the semi-Reimannian geometry of general relativity. In more than two dimensions (and spacetime is $4$-dimensional), that comparison does not work even vaguely, because the curvature has components to it, $20$ for our $3+1$-dimensional spacetime.

But it is not actually "thickness" in either case. I don't think the analogy is very good even in two dimensions.

> My question is: Do we have any idea how the thickness varies inside the Schwarzschild radius? Does the curvature go to infinity (graphed by an orthogonal vertical line) at the singularity?

Yes, we do: for the Schwarzschild geometry, the (orthonormal-frame) Riemann curvature components are either $0$ or proportional to $M/r^3$, where $r$ is the Schwarzschild radial coordinate. They diverge to infinity near the $r = 0$ singularity, as do certain curvature scalars.

> Or does the curvature go to infinity at the Schwarzschild radius? Can a form of Calculus be profitably applied to a mass-object of infinite thickness?

To your first question, it does not: at the Schwarzschild radius, $r = 2M$, curvature is quite finite and well-behaved. Nothing physically special happens to a particle crossing the Schwarzschild radius. There the Schwarzschild *coordinates* have a singularity, but the curvature does not. Since coordinates are simply labels we used to order events and calculate things, this is not a physical issue.

If I understand your intent in the second question correctly (are you referring to infinite *curvature*?), then no, classically the central curvature singularity is not treated as part of spacetime, and things that reach the singularity no longer exist.

Comment: I'm thinking about whether the concept of the Calculus (the creation of coherent interpretations that are on another plane or level or have a different philosophical context) could be usefully applied to interpret such things.

Comment: @Tim: you have a very peculiar notion of 'Calculus' that I don't understand; therefore, I can't answer your question. However, I can tell you that mathematical calculus is used to study (and even define) curvature, and also used to study curvature singularities through the behavior of spacetime *around* them--a sort of 'indirect' method.

Comment: @Stan Liou. The fact that some *components* of Riemann tensor diverge does not automatically imply the existence of a singularity. It could be just an apparent singularity as it happens for the metric tensor in Schwarzschild coordinates for $r \to 2M$. The singularities have to be investigated using scalar fields. I do not remember what actually happens at $r=0$ for a S. black hole. Since a true singularity exists there and $Ric_{ab}=0$ I guess that $Riem_{abcd}Riem^{abcd}$ diverges for $r\to 0$.

Comment: @VM9: You are mostly right. I said the components are proportional to $M/r^3$, but this is not technically true in interior Schwarzschild chart, but rather in the orthonormal tetrad generated by them. Divergence of scalar invariant is sufficient, but not necessary, as they cannot detect a nonscalar singularity (e.g., in a pp-wave spacetime), but fortunately one doesn't have to use them. There are some theorems about the presence of singularities in terms of the divergence of the tetrad components, but yes, I was playing it loose here.

Comment: Right, you were using tetrads! Thanks for your clarification.

Comment: @VM9: np, I should edit it for clarity anyway. Thanks.